# Is it possible to delete a Telegram Bot Conversation?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Can Telegram bot delete whole conversation with me? For example, if I open Telegram, I don't want to see a bot in my conversations list. Is it possible with Bot API or else?

Answer (score 0):

No, till now, [official api documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) doesn't mention such an api for deleting the whole conversation and you can only delete single messages at a time.